# Set maximum pan distance (limiting how far the user can pan)

Tags: three.js

I've been looking into this and cannot figure out a good way to do it, most things that I do end up with the camera becoming disorientated.

Essentially I want the user to be able to pan around the scene but only to maximum and minimum distance both in x and y. By default the user seems to be able to pan indefinitely which can result in the scene becoming miles away from where the user is actually looking so I want a way to prevent this, does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this.

I'm using the TracballControls with the adding touch support by Eberhard Graether and Mark Lundin.

Comment: Check camera position and clamp it between certain values?

Comment: Unfortunately the controls seem to update a different vector and changing the camera causing all kinds of perspective issues.